# Extracting variable name from bspline-coeffiecient in R with regex

Tags: regex, r

In a linear model, I have some splines, using the `bs` function from the `splines` package (like `lm(y ~ bs(x, 3))`).

In the model summary and model data frame (`colnames(fit$model)`) these terms appear as, e.g., **bs(efc17age, 3)**.

Now I would like to extract the variable name using regular expressions. However,, I just don't understand regex syntax.

This is how far I came:

```
x <- "bs(e17age, 3)1"
sub("bs\\((*?)", "", x)
> [1] "e17age, 3)1"
```

I just want to have "e17age"... It must be so easy, *if* you understand regex...

Comment: `bs\\((.*?)(?:,|\\))`

Comment: If it works (as i'm not super familiar with r), i'll write an answer explaining it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work: `sub("bs\\((.*?)(?:,|\\))", "\\1", x) ` results in `[1] "e17age 3)1"` and `sub("bs\\((.*?)(?:,|\\))", "", x)` results in `[1] " 3)1"`.

Comment: Replacements here seem to work different than I anticipated. The regex is correct but you need to select the rest of the string too (so it then gets replaced), so `bs\\((.*?)(?:,|\\)).*` would work with \\1, `.*` replacing the `3)1` from your first result. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following snippet:

```
x <- "bs(e17age, 3)1"
sub("^bs\\(([^,]*).*", "\\1", x)
```

Regex `^bs\\(([^,]*).*` matches `bs(` at the start of the string, then captures any number of characters other than `,` with `([^,]*)`, and then matches any character up to the end. With the replacement string `\\1`, we get our captured text back.

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/3jsf0S)

Comment: works, and also works for polynomials using the `poly` function (i,.e. term names like __poly(e17age, degree = 3).1__

Comment: This is the combined power of a negated character class (`[^,]`) and capturing groups. If you only have 1 argument, you might want to use a bit extended version that will stop at the closing `)`: `sub("^bs\\(([^,)]*).*", "\\1", x) `. If you come across nested parentheses and need to deal with them, Perl-like regex can also deal with that, just drop me a comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess, this will be enough for now, hoping there will be no need to get in touch with nested parantheses or similar ;-)